# How do I translate an HTML input field to "simple_form"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have the following HTML input field:

```
<input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="Enter your name" id="login-name" />
<label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
```

I want to translate it into my `simple_form` field so it will have the same properties like classes, id's etc.

```
<%= f.input :email%>
```

Is there a way to add HTML properties inside the `simple_form` field?

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from [simple_form documentation on Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

```
<%= simple_form_for  @user  do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username, label: 'Your username please' %>
  <%= f.input :password, hint: 'No special characters.' %>
  <%= f.input :email, placeholder: 'user@domain.com' %>
  <%= f.input :remember_me, inline_label: 'Yes, remember me' %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

By default it contains `labels`.

Also, specific options in input call will overwrite the defaults:

```
 <%= f.input :username, input_html: { class: 'special' } %>
```

Have a look at their Github page, everything is there.